# Magento 2:ERROR: Front controller reached 100 router match iterations

Tags: magento2, routing

I got error when trying to do like this extention 
http://inchoo.net/magento-2/routing-in-magento-2/
it work ok but when I add a `foreach` to check the url, I got error

> Front controller reached 100 router match iterations
>   #0 [internal function]: Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))

Comment: Refer may be helpful to you https://merchantprotocol.com/knowledgebase/solved-front-controller-reached-100-router-match-iterations/